# How to append array to dictionary?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, xcode, dictionary

I'm trying to append a dictionary to my array, but i have no idea how to go about it, even after reading  a bunch of threads.

I have this struct:

```
// MARK: - Main
struct Main: Codable {
    var objects: [Object]
}

// MARK: - Object
struct Object: Codable {
    let id:Int
    let url: String
    var displayname: String
    let inventory: [Inventory]
    let media: [Media]
}
```

And a variable of this struct:

```
var searchresult: Main?
```

Let's say i want to append the below dictionary to above struct/variable object array:

```
{
"id":12994,
"url":"www.google.com",
"displayname":"google",
"inventory":[],
"media":[]
}
```

How would i go about doing this? I have been trying to read other threads, but dont really understand much :( I want the final result to be that the object array gets filled with a bunch of different dictionaries that i can then search through, like below:

```
"meta":{
"status":"OK",
"count":5,
"offset":0,
"totalcount":5
},
"objects":[
{
"id":8918,
"url":"example",
"displayname":"example",
"inventory":[],
"media":[]
},
{
"id":12994,
"url":"example",
"displayname":"example",
"inventory":[],
"media":[]
},
{
"id":19559,
"url":"example",
"displayname":"example",
"inventory":[],
"media":[]
},
{
"id":21100,
"url":"example",
"displayname":"example",
"inventory":[],
"media":[]
},
{
"id":22250,
"url":"Example",
"displayname":"Example",
"inventory":[],
"media":[]
}
]
```

Comment: Create an `Object` from the dictionary and then append it: `searchresult?.objects.append(object)`

Comment: @vadian

Hi Vadian! 

I have this variable: result2.objects  

I am trying to append it to my self.searchresult?.objects.append(contentsOf: result2.objects)

but it prints out nil, how come?

Comment: Then `searchresult` is `nil` (not initialized)

Comment: @vadian

Ok, i see. Is there a simple way to initialize it? I am trying but keep getting a bunch of errors. I'll try looking it up during the day.

Comment: Add your code and the errors you get.

Comment: @vadian

var searchresult= Main?()

Errors: No exact matches in call to initializer. 1. Candidate has Partially matching parameter list (main), 2. Candidate has partially matching parameter list (nilLiteral: ()), 3. Candidate has partially matching paramter list (from: Decoder)

Comment: Is it a dictionary or json data you have? It looks like it's json.

Comment: @joakimDanielson

Hey! I'm not entirely sure, i think its a dictionary with json data? The dictionary is used for get and put requests.

Comment: You must now what kind of data you are working with in your code? Anyway you need to find a way to convert your data to Object (how depends on if it is json or not). And why do you need Main at all, are you going to send the data somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

try `searchresult?.objects.append(your_dictionary)`. You can then later get by `searchresult?.objects`. And make sure that `Inventory` and `Media` classes/structs also are codable.